# How can I validate a string with accents in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm trying to set up a form in wordpress in french using javascript and contact form 7. I'm trying to make an hidden conditionnal field that appear when I choose a certain option in a scrolldown menu. Everythings work fine until I have options that contains accentuated characters. My problem is that when I'm trying to validate a string that contains accented characters, my form doesn't work anymore.

Here's my form code

```
<div id="contactForm">
<li>
  <label for="develop-leadership">Catégorie de formation</label>[select develop-leadership id:develop-leadership include_blank class:contactForm "Développement du leadership" "second string" "third string"]
</li>
<li>
  <div class="hide" id="hide1">
  <label for="develop-leadership">Tell us why not</label>[text develop-leadership /50 id:develop-leadership class:contactForm "some text"]
   </div>

</li>
</div>
```

Here's my javascript code

```
/*! jQuery script to hide certain form fields */


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hide1").hide();

    //Show the text field only when Developpement du leadership is selected
    $('#develop-leadership').change(function() {
        if ($("#develop-leadership").val() == "Développement du leadership") {
            $("#hide1").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#hide1").hide();
        }
    });


});
```

Any idea how i might fix this? I have been searching all day to find what could fix it

Comment: Have you tried `.value` instead of `.val()`?

Comment: That sounds like a typical character encoding problem. What encoding did you save your documents in?

Comment: I would try to avoid writing your own validation. Don't reinvent the wheel. Look into using Jquery Validate(or something similar) with globalization. Also, you may want to do your validation on the backend. Front-end validation can not be your only validation, as it can be easily stepped around.

Comment: try to put the charset="UTF-8" attribute in your script tag ?

Comment: In addition to the suggestions above, the actual value of `#develop-leadership` might be different than the text on the label. Be sure to check the generated html by the contact form plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/s8q43cop/), which will show how to make it work. Here is the code, which you need. The `.val()` method is only for form fields, like `<input>`. For other HTML tags, you'll have to use the `.html()` method. I've also added some extra IDs, which were missing.

HTML:

```
<div id="contactForm">
  <li>
    <label for="develop-leadership">Catégorie de formation</label>
  </li>
  <li id="hide1" class="hide">
     <label id="develop-leadership" for="develop-leadership">Développement du leadership</label>
  </li> 
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#hide1").hide();
if ($("#develop-leadership").html() === "Développement du leadership") {
   $("#hide1").show();
}
```